# How I can drop a specific table using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I need to drop a specific table from my database using sequelize.

I tried many times but It deletes all tables.

I want to delete only what I defined as CategoryName.

I try this but not working with me

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');
const Category = require('../models/category');

exports.postDeleteCategory = (req,res,next) => {
    const categoryId = req.body.categoryId;
    const categoryName = req.body.categoryName+'s';
    Category.destroy({
        where: {
            id: categoryId
        },
        force: true
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Destroyed Category');
            sequelize.drop(categoryName+'s');
            res.redirect('/categories');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

It is dropped all tables not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here drops all the tables.

```
sequelize.drop(categoryName+'s');
```

To drop your table just do

```
await Category.drop()
```

Comment: I don’t want to drop Category table I want to drop another table by passing name of the table

Comment: @othmanali Then do this:
sequelize.getQueryInterface().dropTable('tableName')